# How to properly set indexes?

Tags: python, file-io

I am making a program which a allows me to set bookings to a text file which will then update the text file however i am having a problem with my for loop and my 2D array

```
newMemberArr = []
memberArr = []
def SetBookings():

NoNights = int(input("Please Enter the ammount of Nights you want to book, Max is 14"))
NewPoints = NoNights * 1000
Surname = str(input("Please Enter your surname"))

with open("SampleData2017.txt", mode = "r", encoding = "utf-8" ) as Data:
    for line in Data:
        memberArr.append(line.split(","))
```

The code below is where i am having the issue. it says that 'i' is referenced before assignment, however if i change the order it says that 'index' is referenced before assignment

```
    index = memberArr.index(i)
    for i in memberArr[index][1]:

        if Surname in memberArr:
            memberArr[index][4] = memberArr[index][4] + NoNights
            memberArr[index][5] = memberArr[index][5] + NewPoints
```

memberArr is the 2D array which holds the data inside of the text file

Comment: What is `memberArr`?

Comment: Yeah, well, you are using a variable before you gave it a value. What's your question exactly?

Comment: Can you give an example of the input?

Comment: Imagine this as a dialog between you and your computer. You say: "Computer, give me the index of the item `i`!". PC: "Sorry, what's `i`?". You: "Oops...ok then, please give me all items within the sub-list of `index`". PC: "Sorry...what's `index`?"

Answer (score 2):

`i` **is** being referenced before assignment on the line:

```
index = memberArr.index(i)
```

At this point, the variable i has not been declared and hasn't had a value assigned to it - so you **cannot** use its value (it doesn't have one). It only has a value from the next line onwards:

```
for i in memberArr[index][1]:
```

It's impossible to give you more a more specific answer than this, given how little information you have provided (e.g. what is contained in `memberArr`, what is `index` actually meant to be etc.)